# need help with DB design - Rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm new to rails and need some help with DB design.

It is basically `category`, `product`, `quantity`, price...type of tables.

I have 4 categories: `CatA CatB CatC CatD`

Each category above will have multiple products in them:

```
CatA - ProductA1, ProductA2, ProductA3
CatB - ProductB1, ProductB2, ProductB3
CatC - ProductC1, ProductC2, ProductC3
CatD - ProductD1, ProductD2, ProductD3
```

Each Product then has a `type, rating, quantity, price, volume`

Would it be good to have one big Product table with columns: Category, Product Name, Type, Rating, etc..ec..

or have different tables for `Category, Product, Type` which relationship will they have `belongs_to or has_many`?

I'm looking at it from Admin Point of View. If a user wants to add a new product then they'll first select category from drop down, type product name, select product type etc. having everything in one table will be easy but is that efficient?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want `products` and `categories` tables.

`Product` will `belong_to :category` and `Category` will `has_many :products`.

You'll need a `category_id` column in the `products` table to make the association.

I wouldn't recommend a `types` table -- just have the type as a column in the `products` table.  Don't use the word "type" though, go with "kind" as Rails uses "type" for Single Table Inheritance so you might run into some weirdness if you're not using it for that.

Comment: Why de-normalize "types"? How is that different from Category? Stick with good DB practice, don't duplicate data. If a Type is reusable by more than one Product, definitely have a types table.

Comment: Yeah, "type" is just another kind of category.

Comment: Based on your info above, it looked like type was more of an attribute than a relation.  If you intend to query based on the type (as opposed to just displaying it as part of a product), then I would agree that another table is the way to go.